# Getting friendly name from Windows NT device path

Tags: windows-7, registry, driver, device

Let's say that I have already determined the following device path for a certain bridge device:

```
\Device\USBSER000
```

How would I be able to programatically look up its device entry in the registry, i.e.,

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\USB\Vid_xxxx&Pid_xxxx\xxxxxxxxxx
```

Thanks in advance.